# Merge on many variables on python

Tags: python, loops, join, pandas, merge

I have a `df` like that :

```
 id_1    id_2    id_3   id_4 etc. 
 001     002     003     004
```

I have another `df` called `df_referential`, which I can find a match between id and his match.

`df_referential` is like that :

```
 id    Name    
 001    "Parents"    
002    " Child"    
003    "Music"
etc.
```

I would like a `df` on that form :

```
id_1    Name_1    id_2   Name_2   id_3    Name_3   etc.
001    "Parents"  002    "Child"   003    Music
```

I try this code :

```
for x in range(1,len(df.columns)):
    test_join_{0}.format(x)= pd.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.id_{0}.format(x)),df_referential, left_on='id{0}.format(x)',right_on='id')
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you know how merge on many columns please ?

Thks

Comment: Are you using Pandas? If so, that's important to mention in the question.

Comment: It looks like you're using Pandas.  If so, you really need to add that tag to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry yes i'm using Pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(df.columns)):
    col = df.columns[i]
    df = df.merge(df_referential, left_on = col, right_on = 'id', how='left', suffixes = ['', '_%s'%i])
```

Comment: Thks Sam, your code is almost that i want, but le the new df contain only 4 rows instead of 16 000 rows. i don't understand how it's possible.

Comment: Sorry, I think the problem could be resolved by adding a "how = 'left' " to the merge statement so that way it keeps all records in df and only the records that match in df_referential

Comment: thks a lot SAM, it's working.

Do you know how to keep only names_1 ... names_n ?

Comment: try something like for col in df.columns: if col.find('id')>-1: df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace = True)

Comment: or you could do: df[[col for col in df.columns if col.find('name')>-1]]

Comment: thks a lot Sam, it's perfect !